# How to backrgroundColor full in TextSpan on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text, textspan

[image: How to Add divider onEnter TextSpan and why backrgroundColor not full?]

```
Widget richText() {
      return Positioned(
        top: h / 1.9,
        right: w / 4.9,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: wA / 1.365,
            height: hA / 2.3,
            child: RichText(
              softWrap: true,
              textScaleFactor: 1,
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              text: TextSpan(
                style: GoogleFonts.notoNaskhArabic(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  wordSpacing: 0.05,
                  letterSpacing: 0.05,
                  height: 2.2,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: [
                  for (int u = 0; u < _items.length; u++)
                    (u) > 0
                        ? TextSpan(
                            style: TextStyle(
                                backgroundColor: (indexBackground) == u
                                    ? Colors.amber
                                    : Colors.transparent),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: (indexBackground) == u
                                        ? Colors.amber
                                        : Colors.transparent),
                                text: _items[u]['text'],
                                recognizer: LongPressGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onLongPress = () {
                                    indexBackground = u;
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                              ),
                              const WidgetSpan(
                                alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                                child: SizedBox(width: 3),
                              ),
                              WidgetSpan(
                                alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                                child: waqaf(u + 1),
                              ),
                              const WidgetSpan(
                                alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 8,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        : const TextSpan(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

How to solve this?

I have set the outer border of the Container and padding to 0, but it doesn't work like the code below.
I've also tried using widgetSpan to put text in, but the text just gets messy.
Why not full **colorBackground** in **TextSpan**?
Because, my code not worked. This photo is the result.

Comment: Update your index inside setState : setState(() {
                          indexBackground = u;
                        });

Comment: Is your intention to set background color for the entire rich text? If that's the case, you need to set the text style for the outermost text span.

Comment: I mean, I want to make a full backgroundColor like the photo I marked in this red box

[Foto](https://i.ibb.co/tQ4J6RP/Text-Span-2.jpg)

Comment: Yes, I have set the outer border of the Container and padding to 0,
`

Comment: I mean replacing `TextSpan` with WidgetSpan and then Conatiner<Text> also you better will be adding space before or after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra space will help `text: "${_items[u]['text']} ",`

```dart
TextSpan(
  text:"${_items[u]['text']} ",
  style: TextStyle(
      backgroundColor: (indexBackground) == u
          ? Colors.amber
          : Colors.transparent),
  recognizer: LongPressGestureRecognizer()
```

Seems like text doesn't have enough padding.

If you like more, use `WidgetSpan` with a container padding and bg color.

Comment: I've tried using WidgetSpan to put the text, but it's a mess. It doesn't fit what I want, I want it like this photo. BackroundColor TextSpan full from start to finish (I marked the red box).

However, in the photo above, it looks like there is padding so the backgroundColor is not full
[I want this backround color full](https://i.ibb.co/tQ4J6RP/Text-Span-2.jpg)

Comment: you need to handle only left and right padding, also you can just add a space at end as I mentioned

Comment: I just updated my code, I've set all padding to 0

Comment: Thanks, solved.
I'm adding space at end, and i remove widgetSpan>SizeBox